# Do i need to add the constraint line I used in a strong entity when I'm making a create statement for a weak entity?

Tags: sql, oracle

So if i have a strong entity like:

```
Book (bid, price)
PK (bid)
Constraint chk_book_price check (price >= 0)
```

And weak entity like:

```
Store (bid, storename)
FK (bid)
```

Do i need to add the constraint line I used in the strong entity when I'm making a create statement for the weak entity?

So like

```
Create Table Store
(
    bid number (4),
    storename varchar2 (20),
    Foreign Key (bid) references Book (bid),
    Constraint chk_book_price check (price >= 0)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to.
you just need to have constraints for the `STORE` table in the definition.

```
Create Table Store
(
    bid number (4),
    storename varchar2 (20),
    Foreign Key (bid) references Book (bid),
);
```

So for table `BOOK` you only need to create constraints for itself like

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK (
BID NUMBER(5),
PRICE NUMBER(7, 2)
CONSTRAINT CHK_BOOK_PRICE CHECK (PRICE >= 0)
)
```

`FOREIGN KEY CONSTRIANT` refers to a unique or primary key of another table and before you can create `FOREIGN KEY` you must create a parent table first with `PRIMARY OR UNIQUE KEY`.

Either you create `BOOK` table first or use `ALTER TABLE` to create constraints when both tables are created.

Comment: ... which means that your CREATE TABLE BOOK statement is missing the primary key constraint (one way or another).

Comment: Yeah, I should rephrase it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! and yea I created the store table first so the FK can reference it.